# Can I use a string in C and get two different data values from it?

Tags: c

Is it possible to take a string and get two different values from it to store in different type variables, more specifically, an integer and a character.

Brief example:

**string : "A - 3"**

**int number : 3**

**char name : 'A'**

I've seen people take multiple int from a string but nothing worked for me. I should add I am very new to C, so I don't really know how to mess around with it too much.

Its for a slide puzzle minigame where I need to read a text file with all instructions from the user, formatted with what direction each number block goes ("8 r" = 8 goes right), and print to the terminal each and every move. If anyone could suggest how I could take an int and char at the same time from a line on a file, I would also be grateful.

Comment: How do you normally read input, from standard input or from a file? Do you perhaps use `scanf` or `fscanf`? If you look them up, I'll bet you also find an `sscanf` function to parse strings. Try using that.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: Q: Is it possible to take a string and get two different values?  A: Sure.  It's called [parsing](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/3853/parse). You can "parse" values from "input text".  Three approaches (of many) include [strtok()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html), [strstr()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcasestr.3.html) or [sscanf()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3p.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`fscanf()`](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2), defined in `stdio.h`, to read from a file:

```c
int fscanf (FILE *stream, const char *format-string, argument-list)
```

`stream` is a file you previously opened. `fscanf()` returns the number of fields that it successfully converted and assigned. The return value does not include fields that the fscanf() function read but did not assign.

Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* f = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    int value;
    char ch;
    if (fscanf(f, "%d - %c", &value, &ch) != 2)
        printf("Error");

    printf("value: %d\nchar: %c\n", value, ch);

    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

File **file.txt** content:

```
100 - A
```

Output:

```
value: 100
char: A
```

---

If your purpose is to parse a string, the simplest way to achieve this is to use [`strtok()`](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5.8) defined in `string.h` header:

```c
char *strtok(char *string1, const char *string2);
```

Comment: Tried doing something like this, but probably missed something. It's working great now, thanks man!